# Form.Show Method (IWin32Window) and Form.Owner, how to set owner shown form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't access `Form.Show(IWin32Window)`, but I can use `Application.OpenForms[0].Owner`.

How do I set `Owner` if I have `IWin32Window` parent window?

I write **COM DLL** module to application, in dll i use **WINFORMS** library without access Form.Show(IWin32Window).

I can't use

```
form.Owner = this;
```

Comment: can you show some code? How do you call form.show method?

Comment: all i have - winApplication.Start(). And than library somewhere runs form)